# Fit Text into Button

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap and javascript for a quiz.

The text in the buttons is sometimes longer than the body of the buttons, and on mobile the text doesn't fit into the button,so we cannot read the text.
How can I make the text fit into button body? Thank you!.

```html
<button id="answer_a_btn" class="answer btn     btn-default btn-lg btn-block" role="button">
                       <span><p id="answer_a" style="width: 100%"></p></span>
          </button>
<button id="answer_b_btn" class="answer btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block" role="button">
                           <span><p id="answer_b" style="width: 100%">    </p></span>
          </button>
<button id="answer_c_btn" class="answer btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block" role="button">
                       <span max-width: 100%><p id="answer_c" style="width:   100%"></p></span>
             </button>
```

Comment: your question is a little unclear. but try setting the width to pixels instead of percentages

Comment: Specify your font size. Make exact width adjustments. Add padding.

Comment: Avoid wrapping your `<p>` answers in a `<span>` tag also; that's not really valid HTML. You could just as easily add the `id` attrobute to the `<span>`.

Answer (score 0):

use media queries to adjust the `font-size` or use dynamic values for the font-size such as `vw` or use a plugin like [succinct](https://mikeking.io/succinct/)

Answer (score 0):

try using pixels instead:

```
style="width: 200px;"
```

Answer (score -2):

try to use `bootstrap` extra small button

might help you 
have a look to code snippet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Button</h2>
  <p>The .btn-xs class makes extra small buttons:</p>            
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs">Extra small Default Button</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-xs">Extra small Info Button</button>      
</div>

</body>
</html>
```